# Why passing a weak reference to a block prevents an object from being retained?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, reference-counting

We all know that blocks retain objects they capture. We also know we can avoid this by passing a weak reference to an object into a block. But why it works this way? To retain an object means to increase its retain count by one. Why it makes difference to pass a weak reference? Being weak or strong it will still point to the same object, and this object's retain count will be increased by block. Am I right? So why object's retain count doesn't get increased if we pass a weak reference to an object inside a block? How does it work inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort of think of a block as an object which has an "instance variable" for each captured variable, which is initialized with the value of the corresponding captured variable at the time the block is created.

In ARC, the block's "instance variables" have the same ownership specifier as the corresponding captured variable. So if a captured variable of object-pointer type is `__strong` (the default), the block's "instance variable" is also `__strong`, so it retains the object pointed to for the lifetime of the block. If a captured variable of object-pointer type is `__strong`, the block's "instance variable" is also `__weak`, hence it is a zeroing weak reference to the object pointed to.

Answer (score 3):

Weak references do not increase the retain count, weak references are simply pointers to the object, and if the object no longer exist, then the weak property is set to nil, ARC handles this. I don't believe that the objects retain count will be increased by a weak reference inside the block.

> Because a weak reference does not keep a strong hold on the instance it refers to, it is possible for that instance to be deallocated while the weak reference is still referring to it. Therefore, ARC automatically sets a weak reference to nil when the instance that it refers to is deallocated.

Documentation link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

As far as specific info regarding how ARC works with blocks I found this from apple, which wasn't much help with your question:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

However, this paragraph might be helpful in understanding how blocks retain their local variables:

> Blocks are called closures in other languages such as Python, Ruby and Lisp, because they encapsulate state when they are declared. A block creates a const copy of any local variable that is referenced inside of its scope.

From: http://www.raywenderlich.com/9438/how-to-use-blocks-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

Answer (score 1):

You might want to understand how closure works in general.

Take the following code as an example,

```
var name = "NSNoName"
NSLog("Original name: %@ <%p>", name, name)

let takeName: (String) -> Void -> () = {
    name in
    return {
        NSLog("Name inside block: %@ <%p>", name, name)
    }
}

let  returnName = takeName(name)
name = "NSNoFame"
returnName()

NSLog("Changed name: %@ <%p>", name, name)
```

Initially, the value of **name** variable is "NSNoName". When I print the name at this time, I get the result,

```
Original name: NSNoName <0x7f8fb86004a0>
```

I have a simple closure which takes the string as a parameter. I call the closure with the same name object, as a result the block creates its own copy of the object. Then, I go ahead and change the **name**  object, and now, if I call the block, to print the name, the block has the same original value which was passed to it. But, the object is different, which means that block created a new object with the same value.

```
Name inside block: NSNoName <0x7f8fb8602510>
```

The last NSLog, prints a different value since it is already changed and has some different value,

```
Changed name: NSNoFame <0x7f8fb8603ae0>
```

This is the reason that you want to tell a block, to create a weak reference to the object, which means if the original object does not exist any more, **nil** the reference object created inside block.

While with Objective C, it seems to be little bit different though,

```
@interface TestViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation TestViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.name = @"NSNoName";

    NSLog(@"Original name: %@ <%p>", self.name, self.name);

    typedef void(^ReturnNameBlock)();

    ReturnNameBlock (^takeName)(NSString*) = ^ReturnNameBlock(NSString *name) {
        return ^{
            NSLog(@"Name inside block: %@ <%p>", name, name);
        };
    };

    ReturnNameBlock returnName = takeName(self.name);

    self.name = @"NSNoFame";

    returnName();

    NSLog(@"Changed name: %@ <%p>", self.name, self.name);

}

@end
```

My Log appears like this,

```
Original name: NSNoName <0x103ae34c0>
Name inside block: NSNoName <0x103ae34c0>
Changed name: NSNoFame <0x103ae3520>
```

If you look at the log, the block owns the original self.name object as both have the same, memory address. Although viewController does not own this anymore, when we change the self.name = "NSNoFame", the block still retains the same instance of the object.

The difference in swift and objective is that, Objective C block retains the original instance of the object passed to it, while swift closure creates a copy of the original instance variable.

Comment: This seems to be Swift code; the OP is asking about ObjC.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It does not seem to be much different, however there is a conclusion I reached to with Objective C block.